Aliens give man super enhanced memory
I watched a pilot episode for an american TV show, I believe it was on DVD in the UK about 2003 but I don't know if it had just been released.
In it aliens had visited Earth and helped abolish war, famine, disease etc and had been widely accepted as valuable allies. They recruited the protagonist (all I remember about him was that he was male) and give him super enhanced memory. I THINK someone asked him what he had for lunch when he was in school and he remembered???
Soon after his enhancement he's contacted by some sort of resistance who don't trust the aliens. They want him to be a double agent.
I don't remember anything about plot but I assume he accepted, otherwise it would have been a very short TV series!

Sounds like Earth: Final Conflict which ran from 1997-2002. From Wiki:

The story begins three years after the Taelons arrived on Earth. The Taelons have used their advanced technology to help humanity achieve a better quality of life. However, the North American Taelon Companion, Da'an, is targeted by an assassin while making a speech. Jonathan Doors, a businessman with close ties to the Taelons, is killed while Da'an is unharmed. Da'an is impressed by Police Commander Boone's work in protecting him from the assassination attempt, and offers him a spot as a Taelon Protector, a personal bodyguard and envoy for a particular Taelon.
Boone finds out that Jonathan Doors faked his own death so that he could focus on an underground resistance movement that he founded in secret. Doors believes the Taelons have sinister intentions, and wants to find out their true motives. He also believes that the Taelons had something to do with the murder of Boone's wife. Because of this, Boone agrees to work as a double agent for the resistance in order to find answers. He accepts Da'an's offer to become a Protector, and receives a Cyber-Viral Implant (CVI) that gives him enhanced mental abilities – including perfect recall.

In the second episode, an FBI agent implanted with CVI shows Boone how it works by asking him what he had for lunch in junior high at a certain date in 1987. Here's the intro:




Yep that's it! Now I just need to find where I can watch it!
